# Calling the record save action in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function that alerts the user if fields are not filled in. If they are all filled in then it saves. I am getting an error with using `"{!Save}"` in my javascript.

> Unknown property 'AccountStandardController.Save'

```
if(status = 'Final'){
                if(GHCountry = '' ||
                  GHCity = '' ||
                  USHState = '' ||
                  USHCity = '' ||
                  OwnershipType = '' ||
                  MaaActivity = '' ||
                  OwnershipStage = '' ||
                  vision = '' ||
                  mission = '' ||
                  values = '' ||
                  marketShare = '' ||
                  marketCap = '' ||
                  sharePrice = '' ||
                  sales = '' ||
                  sharePriceDate = '' ||
                  weekChange = '' ||
                  strategy = '' ||
                  priority1 = '' ||
                  forwardLookingObjective = '' ||
                  pyResults = '' ||
                  priority1 = '' ||
                  priority2 = '' ||
                  plannedActivities = '' ||
                  priority4 = '' ||
                  priority5 = '' ||
                  initiatives = '' ||
                  status = ''){
                    alert('All fields must be filled when Account Plan is Final');
                   }else{
                       //save
                       '{!Save}';
                   }
            }else{
                //save
                '{!Save}';
            }
```

How can I save the record via javascript?

Comment: The JavaScript is in a button or a vf page?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `<apex:actionFunction` to call a method in Apex from javascript. Please find the below example on how to implement it.

```
<apex:page controller="t">
<script>
    function myJavascriptFunc(){
        alert('Entered Javascript') ;
        CallApexMethod() ;
    }
</script>
<apex:form >
<apex:actionFunction name="CallApexMethod" action="{!myActionInController}" onComplete="alert('After apex method') ;"/>
  <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:commandButton value="Hit Me" onclick="myJavascriptFunc() ;"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```